# Where is the models folder in Phoenix Framework version 1.4?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In Phoenix framework 1.2 there is a models folder, but is it in version 1.4?

In version 1.2 models directory is in app->web.  After checking entire folder structure models folder does not exists.

Answer (score 8):

If you use `mix phoenix.new` you will still get the old project structure along with your models folder. However, since Phoenix 1.3.0 was released, the default project structure has changed. Using the new command `mix phx.new` we can see that there is no longer a dedicated models folder.

With that release, Phoenix introduced contexts: dedicated modules that expose and group related functionality. Models will no longer go into a single models folder, rather, they will be grouped into different context modules according to their functionality.

For more info, please refer to the 1.3.0 release blog post here (the Contexts section): https://phoenixframework.org/blog/phoenix-1-3-0-released

Answer (score 3):

After 1.2, Phoenix stopped using the Rails-like `models` syntax and design; instead, Phoenix now separates data models into `schemas` and ORM functions into `contexts` when these resources are generated.

The directory structure of Phoenix also changed at version >= 1.3; now your primary application modules are all in `./lib/`, with non-web and database-related (schemas, contexts) modules in `./lib/appname/` and web-facing modules (controllers, views, etc) in `./lib/appname_web/`.

If you run `mix phx.gen.context Accounts User users email:string username:string` in your project, the generator will generate the `./lib/appname/accounts/` directory, containing a file called `/accounts/user.ex` that contains your user `schema` & `changeset` and a file called `/accounts/accounts.ex` that contains your database CRUD logic related to your user schema.

Check out the changelog in TGO's answer and also check out [the official Phoenix docs about Contexts](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/contexts.html#content) for a clearer picture of Phoenix's current Context design